# Error "Build service could not create build operation: unknown error while handling message: unknownSession"

Tags: xcode, xcode13

How do you debug that kind of Xcode's error when you don't
have anything useful to start with?

> Build service could not create build operation: unknown error while handling message: unknownSession

When having that issue, the 'Clean Build Folder' is starting, but never ends.

The only work around that I found is to quit Xcode and start it again.

Things that I already done:

- Manually delete files in DerivedData
- Install the latest 13.4 version

Comment: I'm getting this same error. Have been since the update to 13.4, but it even causes the error on 13.2.1

Comment: @DanVanWinkle, so far, with 13.1 and 13.2 I don't have that error and even another one that I had is not present. Will continue to work with for a full day and go update to 13.4 to see the difference.

Answer (score 2):

For people having that same issue, I suggest you to stay with Xcode 13.2 or lower for now.

Hopefully, 13.5+ or 14.x will fix that issue.